# Swift present ViewController programmatically while showing segues(arrows) in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I really love the graphical interface of the storyboard designer in Xcode, because all the segues are
displayed with an arrow.
[image]

But sometimes, when there is more complexity (e.g. variable to pass), I have to use a programatic way to switch to another ViewController.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

// pass variable
nextViewController.email = self.textfieldEmail.text!

self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

I dislike, that some of the segues in my App are displayed with an arrow in storyboard, while the more complex ones are not.
Is there any way to show those more complex segues with an arrow in the Main.storyboard?

Comment: Isn't this what the `prepare(for:sender:)` method of `UIViewController` is for?

Comment: You should review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. You can create segues in interface builder and pass data in prepareForSegue method
2. When using code to switch controllers you can still create segue in your storyboard that you will not use - just for visualisation

Comment: How can I create a segue in my storyboard just for visualization?

Comment: Zoom out a little, now hold ctrl and click and hold on the first view controller, move to the second one and release the mouse button. Segue created.